# validate_on_submit fails on POST when attributes of form fields modified in view function

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a simple `wtforms.RadioField` to accept user selection in a form in my app defined as:

```py
class VoteForm(FlaskForm):
    vote_option = RadioField("Choices", coerce=int)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And my view function is:

```py
@main.route('/poll/<poll_id>/vote', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def vote(poll_id):
    poll = Poll.query.filter_by(id=poll_id).first()
    form = VoteForm()
    form.vote_option.choices = [(o.id, o.option) for o in poll.options]
    form.vote_option.default = poll.options[0].id
    form.process()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.vote_option.data)

    return render_template("vote.html", form=form)
```

And the template is simply:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/form.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}
    {{ wtf.render_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I post from the form, however, it is not validated and nothing is printed to the console.

If I instead remove the modifications to the form in the view function and define the `vote_option` field as:

```
vote_option = RadioField("Choices", choices=[("ONE", "ONE"), ("TWO", "TWO")])
```

The form can be validated as expected. What is going wrong by modifying the attributes of the form in the view function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the call to `form.process()` in the view function solved the problem. Although I am not entirely sure why. I will accept an answer which can explain why.

Comment: I vaguely remember hitting something similar and it was to do with the `coerce=int` option.